# How to detect keyboard spacebar press in matlab？

Tags: matlab

I want to detect how many times the user click spacebar in 5 seconds

Is there any good way to fix this problem?
Thanks

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific please? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 1):

One way to easily read user inputs from the keyboard is to create a new figure and specify a `KeyPressFcn` callback function, which is executed automatically if any key is pressed.

Lets start off by creating a new figure. As we don't need the figure to display anything, let's make it as small as possible (i.e. 1 by 1 pixel) and place it at the lower corner of the display:

```
f = figure('Position',[0,0,1,1]);
```

Now we'll set the `UserData` property of the figure - which we will use as counter - to zero:

```
set(f,'UserData',0);
```

Now let's see what to do when a key is pressed: We can create a small callback function which checks if the pressed button was a space and increases the `UserData` counter if that was the case. We'll call that function `isspace`:

```
function isspace(hObject,callbackData)
    if get(hObject,'CurrentCharacter') == ' '
        set(hObject,'UserData',get(hObject,'UserData')+1);
    end
end
```

Now simply set up the figure to use this function as `KeyPressFcn` by

```
set(f,'KeyPressFcn',@isspace);
```

This already counts the number of times space is pressed. The current value of the counter is read by

```
get(f,'UserData');
```

Now we need the time measurement. This can be done using a `timer`. We'll configure it to go off after 5 seconds and then assing a new value in the base workspace. For that we need a callback function `timerCallback.m`

```
function timerCallback(hObj,eventData)
    assignin('base','nSpace',get(gcf,'UserData'));
    delete(gcf);
    stop(hObj);
    delete(hObj);
end

t = timer('StartDelay',5,'TimerFcn',@timerCallback);
start(t);
```

And that's it: First create the figure, create the timer and after 5 seconds you get the number of key presses in the variable `nSpace` in your workspace and the window is closed.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will test the code and feedback in a few minutes.

Comment: The space counter works well. But when I use the timer, there is an error like this: `The name 'TimerCallback' is not an accessible property for an instance of class 'timer objects'`.

Comment: Oh I made a small typo. It is `'TimerFcn'`, not `'TimerCallback'`. I changed my answer accordingly.